# How to determine the needed permission for my app

Tags: android, permissions

I'd like to know if there is any way to determine the permissions my app needs.

There is a similar question here:[How do I determine why my Android app requires certain permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059377/how-do-i-determine-why-my-android-app-requires-certain-permissions)

But the answer states, that you basically have to find out yourself and I can't believe this.

Is there really no way to tell Eclipse to take a look at my code and determine the needed permissions or something like this? There should be no problem to automate this.

Or is there a way to test permissions on a device. When I install my app on my local device I'm not asked for any permissions.

Any help is really welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no magical way to figure out this now :)

Comment: Normally I get a runtime exception when I am trying to do something that isn't permitted at the test device. So if your app run correctly, I think you are on the safe side.

Comment: I really love downvoters who downvote without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it.
The app crashes and tells you the reason why: it expected some permission(s) declared in its manifest file.

It normally tells you in 2 ways: in a Dialog (FC Dialog) and in the LogCat.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
boolean crashes = true
while (crashes) {
    ReadLogCat()
    AddPermissionFoundMissingAccordingToLogCat()
    crashes = TryAgain()
}
```

PS: This is pseudocode ;)

PPS: You didn't copy this to Eclipse, did you? Just kiddin' ;)

Comment: You're welcome, my friend. I like this humor. Which is also the real way to do it correctly.

Comment: hehe... not helpfull but funny :). I like this humor, too ;).

Comment: Well, in a way, it should even be helpful for it contains all the information just a different representation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define permissions according to what your apps doing, if it's accessing the internet, it needs permission to do it. If it wants to locate you via GPS, it needs a permission for it and no you can't automate it, not officially anyway.

Think your app as a virtual child, you need to grant it permission to do stuff or else it won't do anything. So you have to pretty much decide yourself.

But you need not worry, if you're missing a permission, the log will let you know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

well i won't consider this as official solution for this problem

usually when i miss any permission in my application say  i am using internet connectivity or get tasks but i didn't declared them in manifest

when i run my app i get it in log cat saying internet permission and get tasks permissions are required for this app to run

hope that answer your question

Comment: i thought i said that first

Comment: You answered 2 mins after me.

Comment: may be it was time i took to type

Comment: i won't be bothering you much now i got banned out from here because of low quality answers

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really no way to tell Eclipse to take a look at my code and determine the needed permissions or something like this?

If you have a test suite that adequately tests your app, running the test suite will tell you the needed permissions, because your tests will crash if you do not have them.

> Or is there a way to test permissions on a device. When I install my app on my local device I'm not asked for any permissions.

The permissions that you see on install are based on your `<uses-permission>` elements in your manifest, not some analysis of the app beyond that. Hence, this will not help you. That being said, installing your app by any means other than **`adb`**, such as downloading the app from a Web server, will pop up the permissions dialog, so you can see what prospective users will see at install time.